# Installing an SDK on ANdroid Studio 3.2 project

Tags: android, sdk

I am new at programming Android ...

I created a new  Project... and tried all the recomendations and sample on installing DataCollection.aar into the project.

I have not been able to get it to work  can anyone help?

Thanks

Peter F.

Comment: Show what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

sdk doesn't install on android studio it's another folder via necessary tools for build and develop your android project.when you run android studio you need to define the path of android sdk folder for android studio compiler.and of course you must install jdk.
After that,tell what problem you have actually.